# Add div before the first paragraph the_content

Tags: posts, the-content

I need to add a div before the first paragraph.

Example:

```
<div class="ads-site">ADS </div>

<p>First Paragraph</p>

<p>Second Paragraph</p>
```

My Function:

```
global $post; function my_content_div( $content ) { $content = '<div>My div</div>' . $content; return $content; } add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_div');
```

Comment: Why not just make it part of the template file?

Comment: content-gallery.php

Comment: We ask that questions display some research and implementation effort on the part of the asker. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help] for a few tips which might help you to improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yogenisia's is right that you should use `the_content` filter.

If you want to insert something before the first paragraph, locate the first `<p>` in `$content`, then insert your `div` with `substr_replace`.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'namespace_insert_before_first_paragraph' );

function namespace_insert_before_first_paragraph( $content ) { 
    $my_div = '<div> ... </div>';
    $first_para_pos = strpos( $content, '<p' );
    $new_content = substr_replace( $content, $my_div, $first_para_pos, 0 );

    return $new_content;
}
```

Keep in mind however that many embeds, such as Twitter's, wrap their content in a `<p>...</p>`.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`the_content` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) if that helps:

```
function my_content_div( $content ) {
    $content = '<div>My div</div>' . $content;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_div');
```

You can also add `global $post;` inside the function to get info on the post and have more control when you show the div.

Comment: The div is on top of the image, I need to add before the first paragraph

Comment: `global $post;
function my_content_div( $content ) {
    $content = '<div>My div</div>' . $content;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_div');`